# How do I fix my firebase authentication code, which throws "flutter: Verification failed. An internal error has occurred"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

The full error is: flutter: Verification failed. An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information

working with flutter and firebase authentication. trying to authenticate user phone numbers with this code. Is there any way to fix this problem without having to update the firebase dependencies, and if not what version? the app is for IOS.

My code is below:

```
  Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber({
    required String phoneNumber,
    void Function()? onAutoVerified,
    void Function(String)? onCodeSent,
    void Function(String)? onFailure,
    String? autoRetrievedSmsCodeForTesting,
  }) async {
    firebaseAuthInstance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber.contains('+1') ? phoneNumber : '+1$phoneNumber',
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        try {
          UserCredential userCredentials =
              await firebaseAuthInstance.signInWithCredential(credential);
          _firebaseAuthUser = userCredentials.user;
          onAutoVerified?.call();
        } catch (e) {
          onFailure?.call('$e');
        }
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
        onFailure?.call(exception.message!);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        onCodeSent?.call(verificationId);
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        onFailure?.call('Verification timed out.');
      },
    );
  }
```

my dependencies in pubspec.yaml look like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation: 4.5.0
  provider: 6.0.3
  flutter_svg: 1.1.0
  jiffy: 5.0.0
  firebase_core: 1.20.0
  firebase_auth: 3.11.2
  cloud_firestore: 3.4.1
  flutter_stripe:
    path: ../flutter_stripe/packages/stripe
  mask_text_input_formatter: 2.3.0
  smooth_page_indicator: 1.0.0+2
  is_first_run: 1.0.0
  flutter_contacts: 1.1.4
  blur: 3.1.0
  cloud_functions: 3.3.3
  loading_indicator: 3.1.0
  camera: 0.9.7
  firebase_storage: 10.3.3
  currency_text_input_formatter: 2.1.5
  lottie: 1.3.0
  flutter_branch_sdk: 5.0.0
  intl: 0.17.0
  http: 0.13.4
  path: ^1.8.1
  paginate_firestore: 1.0.3+1
  app_settings: 4.1.8
  url_launcher: 6.1.3
```

the pod file looks like this :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore/WithLeveldb', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '9.3.0'


  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I've checked that the API key is configured properly, which was the most common suggestion, as well as flutter clean, flutter pub get, rm fr podfile.lock, pod update pod install.